# Form Invalid Django Form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-views

***My Template "login_form.html":***

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action=" {% url 'login_form' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
    <div>
        <label>
            <a href="#" value="forgot"> Forgot Password?</a>
        </label>
        <label class="pull-right">
            <a href="#" value="register">Register</a>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

***My views.py:***

```
class LoginFormView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'pv_ui/login_form.html'
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print self, request
        return render(request, template_name)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print self, form
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('video'))
```

***My urls.py:***

```
urlpatterns = patterns('pv_ui.views',
                       url(
                           regex=r'^login/$',
                           view=LoginFormView.as_view(),
                           name='login_form',
                       ),
)
```

***This is the POST data:***

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'username': [u'aaa@gmail.com'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'pphxKPkOhIe0Yk7MqQSj2NYtL2iFlC3b'], u'password': [u'heretherehere']}>,
```

I have stumbled across this problem, where the form does not validate. The post key's values are enclosed inside braces, don't know why that is occurring or is it supposed to occur? Please point me to my mistake. Thank you.

***Important Information:***
Django==1.7.1

Comment: Could you post your full traceback and let us know what version of django you're using?

Comment: I removed the post function and reloaded the server and it works ! I have no idea, why it was not working.

Comment: Oh cool.  Sometimes there can be issues with caching that are hard to debug. I always try restarting the server or opening an incognito window if I can't figure out the problem.